# Should ordered lists of posts from newest to oldest use the reversed attribute?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

An ordered list, `<ol>`, containing items from the newest one to the oldest one should have the `reversed` attribute set? As to indicate *reverse chronological order*?

For example, in a list of blog posts, comments, threads or replies, should it be structured like this?

```
...
<ol reversed>
  <li>newest post<li>
  ...
  <li>oldest post</li>
</ol>
...
```

And in multi-page lists like this? Where `start` should be `total_item_count - page * items_per_page` so that is always assigns the proper value to each list item regardless of what page is being shown?

```
...
Page 4 of 5, showing 10 items per page, 43 items in total
<ol reversed start=13>
  <li>newest post in the page</li>
  ...
  <li>oldest post in the page</li>
</ol>
...
```

Or am I over thinking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use `ol` you can use the `reversed` and `start` attributes in the way you described.

But you probably shouldn’t use `ol` here.

`ol` is not simply for any *sorted* list. Only use `ol` if the order of the `li` is important for the (understanding of the) content.

From the [`ol` definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) (bold by me):

> The `ol` element represents a list of items, where the items have been intentionally ordered, **such that changing the order would change the meaning of the document**.

Examples for `ol`:

- search engine results (if ranked by relevance)
- a list of favorite things (if ranked by favor)
- a list of blog posts where each post is a chapter of a novel (so users should read them in this (and no other) order)

Examples for `ul`:

- search engine results (if there is no ranking algorithm)
- a list of favorite things (if you can’t decide which of those you like more)
- a list of blog posts where each post can be read on its own (i.e. a typical blog)

Even if those last three examples are ordered chronologically or alphabetically, this doesn’t influence the meaning of the content.